# Solidity: bool[](16) vs uint16

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

i'm in progress of Dapp developping.

My question is, in regards of gas economics,

```
bool[] a = new bool[](16);
```

and

```
uint16 a = 0;
```

Both has same gas cost?

Size of array will be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool[] a = new bool[](16);
```

Initialization of a storage fixed-size array creates pointers to **N+1 storage slots**, where N is the array length. Value stored in the first slot is the array length (in your case 16), the rest are values of its items.

In this case (not using `struct`s), there is no optimization related to the datatype length. So even `bool` takes up the whole (32byte) slot.

---

```
uint16 a = 0;
```

Initialization of a storage integer creates a pointer to only 1 storage slot.

You can also save one write operation not using the redundant assign of `0` value, because `0` is the default value anyway. So you can do `uint16 a;` instead of `uint16 a = 0;`

---

So in short, it's ~17 times cheaper to initialize the `uint` (without assigning the zero value) compared to initialization of the array.

Comment: So, same redundancy will be happened at uint8[] and uint16[].
Thanks for your great comment!

Comment: Yes, using either `uint8[]` or `uint16[]` will result in the same redundancy.